# How to deal with a NoReverseMatch error, Reverse for 'item_order' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-urls

I have come across a NoReverseMatch error
`Reverse for 'item_order' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`
I have this view which is called when the template runs,

```
def show_item(request,id):
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = forms.PartialOrderItemForm(request.POST,instance=a)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():

            order.add_to_order(request)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        # it's a GET, create the unbound from. Note request as a Kwarg
        form = forms.PartialOrderItemForm(request.GET)
    # set the test cookie on our first GET request
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context={
#       'categories':categories,
        'form':form,
#       'menu':menu,

    }
    return render_to_response('item.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When this view runs,at some point, it calls this function,

```
def add_to_order(request):  
#   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    # get item slug from post data, return blank if empty
#   item_slug = postdata.get('item_slug','')
    #get quantity added, return 0 if empty
    quantity = postdata.get('quantity',0)
    # fetch the item or return  missing page error_message
    i = get_object_or_404(Item)
    # get items in order
    order_items = get_order_items(request)
    item_in_orders = False
    # check to see if item is already in order
    for order_item in order_items:
        if order_item.item.id == i.id:
            #update the quantity if found
            order_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
            item_in_orders = True
    if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        oi = OrderItem()
        oi.order_id = _order_id(request)
        oi.quantity = quantity
        oi.item = i
        oi.save()
```

the urls.py,

```
from .views import show_item, show_order,get_category
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',get_category, name="item_order_home"),
    url(r'^your_order/$',show_order,name="order_index"),
    url(r'^item/(?P<id>\w+)/$', show_item, name = "item_order"),
#   url(r'^menu/$',get_category,name = "f4l_menu"),
)
```

in the template,here is what am doing

```
{% for category in categories %}
 <h5> {{ category.title }} </h5>
  {% for item in category.item.all %}
   <li><a href="{% url item_order %}">{{item.name}}<span> {{item.price}}frw</span></li><a/>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

what i want to be doing is, their is several items, when i click on one,it redirects me to a form where i submit the quantity of the items i want to buy the, when i submit the form am redirected to an order page.
But instead am across this error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the id value because you specified it in the url

```
{% url item_order item.id %}
```

Comment: hey charl, thanks that worked but i cant accept answer until seven minutes are done.

Comment: If you dont mind, i have this other error that is givin me headaches, i think its more of the logic am using in the views. do u mind checking it out

Comment: I will check it out when i get time yes